# Published var is not Observed with the correct value

Tags: swift

I have a `Published` variable that I can being set in the class, but the value is not read in the view where I'm calling it.

Here's the class:

```
    class Api: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showingAlert = false

    func getRunClub(url: String, completion : @escaping ([RunClubsv2])->()){

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    session.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { (data, response, err) in

        if err != nil{

            print("Unable to get data \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        //decoding JSON

        do {
            self.showingAlert = true. <== Here's where I set it
            print("Class API set alert to: \(self.showingAlert)") <== I can see it being set to true here
            let runclubs = try JSONDecoder().decode([RunClubsv2].self, from: data!)
//            print(runclubs)
            //returning data
            completion(runclubs)

        }
        catch{
            print("Catching error \(error)")
        }
    }
.resume()
}
```

In my View I have it declared `@ObservedObject var foo = Api()`

The gist of the code is:

```
struct RunClubV2: View {
@ObservedObject var foo = Api()
      var body: some View {
        VStack{           
          Text("test")
        }
          .onAppear{
          print("We're going to make the API call for data: \(self.foo.showingAlert)") 
          Api().getRunClub(url: "URL Here") 
              { (runclubs) in
                  print("Alert was set to: \(self.foo.showingAlert)") <== Here the value is set to false.
                  if self.foo.showingAlert == true {
                  print("Show Alert")
              }
            }
          }
        }
    }
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you say `Api()`, that is a *different* API object. So when you say `Api().getRunClub`, the Api whose `getRunClub` you are calling is not the same as the Api `self.foo` which you are examining in the completion handler. It's as if you paint a dog red and then turn around and wonder why this *other* dog is not also red.

Also, the fact that you are saying

```
print("Alert was set to: \(self.foo.showingAlert)")
if self.foo.showingAlert == true {
```

is all wrong. That value is not going to change. The point of having an observable object is that you *observe* it. You are not observing it, you are just looking at it once. So of course it is never going to change.

It looks like what you might be trying to do is perform some time-consuming operation (like networking), put up an alert during that operation, and then take the alert down again at the end of the operation. In that case, your structure is all wrong. You need to use a *binding* to the `@Published` value of your ObservableObject to trigger the presence or absence of the alert. Here is a sketch example of the structure you need:

```swift
class AlertShower : ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAlert = false
    func doYourThing() {
        self.showAlert = true
        // pretend this is your time-consuming operation
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.showAlert = false
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var alertShower = AlertShower()
    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap me") {
            self.alertShower.doYourThing()
        }.fullScreenCover(isPresented: self.$alertShower.showAlert, content: {
            Text("I am the alert")
        })
    }
}
```

If you just run that code, you will see that when you tap the button, the "alert" appears for a while then disappears. That seems to be the sort of thing you are after (though it is hard to tell).

Comment: That makes so much more sense.  Why is it then when I remove `self` I get the following error - Reference to property 'foo' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit.  Is it because I'm in a `list`?

Comment: I tried calling `Api().showingAlert` to see I would have a different value, but it's also still set to `false`

Comment: Yep, that is yet _another_ Api object. Great so now you have three dogs and two of them are not red. Eyeroll.  Please reread my first sentence: Every time you say `Api()`, that is a different API object. Every means every. As for the other error, that is a totally separate matter; just suck it up and say `self.`.

Comment: I don't want three dogs, I just want one dog.  I'm not following what you're saying.  I don't mind sucking it up and using `self.`, but `self.foo` just returned `Api` which is set above. Can you point me in the direction of what I would need to do to get the value of Published var?

Comment: "but `self.foo` just returned Api which is set above" And isn't that exactly what you want? You want to talk to `self.foo` all the time. That is your one dog. — Though, to be honest, if you are going to actively _fetch_ the value of `self.foo.showingAlert`, then I fail to see what the point is of having it be `@Published`, or of having this be an observable object for that matter. You have not explained what `showingAlert` is even supposed to be _for_. If it's supposed to make an alert show, looking at `self.foo.showingAlert` in an `if` statement is not how you do it.

Comment: > You have not explained what showingAlert is even supposed to be for.  That's fair.  I'm actually trying to show an alert if the response fails.  I only have it configured in the current manner for testing.  So I agree it's not correct.  I'll take you sketch code above and try it out.  Thank you for explaining!

Comment: The point is, your title complains that the var is not being observed correctly, and I'm saying, that's right, because you are _not observing it_.